# How to identify activeBindings in my environment without executing them?

Tags: r, environment

Here's an example  activeBinding:

```
invisible(makeActiveBinding('newdev', function(...) {library(grDevices); dev.new(width = 5,height=5,restoreConsole=T)},.GlobalEnv))
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that a variety of functions will cause this item to execute when I use it as an argument.  Examples include

```
class(newdev)   
typeof(newdev)
```

These both return "NULL", but in the process `newdev` executes, creating an unwanted new graphics window. (This is a minor annoyance; other bindings I'd like to use perform more disastrous actions when called at the wrong time)
By comparison,  `ls()` returns names of everything, including the element `"newdev"` without executing it.

In order to perform various other tasks, I would like to be able to do things like  "ls(everything_not_a_activeBinding)" to get all my objects **except** the activeBindings for some action (maybe `save.image()`, for example).

Background: To my knowledge, use of an activeBinding is the only way to issue a function call without having to type the `()` after the function name. If I've missed some obvious way around that which doesn't involve bindings, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bindingIsActive`:

```r
makeActiveBinding("quux", local({i <- 0; function(...) { message("Hello! ", i); i <<- i + 1L; } }), env = .GlobalEnv)
quux
# Hello! 0
quux
# Hello! 1
class(quux)
# Hello! 2
# [1] "numeric"
sapply(ls(), bindingIsActive, .GlobalEnv)
#                quux some_magic_function 
#                TRUE               FALSE 
Filter(function(x) !bindingIsActive(x, env = .GlobalEnv), ls())
# [1] "some_magic_function"
```

Comment: Dang. Sillly me.  I'd tried `bindingIsLocked`  and somehow skipped `bindingIsActive` . Thanks.